# Decimal to Feet- Inches - Fraction

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Function created which will convert a decimal to Feet and Inches but its currently rounding the inches and I need it to convert the inches and the remaining balance to a fraction.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FeetInchesFraction(@V_INCHES DECIMAL)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN(
      SELECT CAST(FLOOR(@V_INCHES/12.0) AS VARCHAR)+''' '+CAST(FLOOR(@V_INCHES%12.0) AS VARCHAR)+'"'
      )
END
GO

SELECT dbo.FeetInchesFraction(68.5)
GO
```

The above currently displays `5' 9"` and I need it to display `5' 8 1/2"`

Comment: Why are you not doing this in your presentation/reporting layer (which will likely have functionality built in for this)? Formatting of data should be performed as the very last step before presenting to a user, not earlier.

Comment: This is for an internal function that updates several database columns of information from a query once the user submits a form which is being converted from an Access system to a PHP SQL system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the function name dbo.udf_ConvertToFraction from [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/convert-numbers-to-fractions-using-sql-server/)

and then modify your code like this

```
ALTER FUNCTION FeetInchesFraction(@V_INCHES DECIMAL(18,2))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN(
      SELECT CAST(FLOOR(@V_INCHES/12.0) AS VARCHAR)+''' '+CAST(FLOOR(@V_INCHES%12.0) AS VARCHAR)+' ' + dbo.udf_ConvertToFraction(@V_INCHES%1.0) + '"'
      )
END
GO

SELECT dbo.FeetInchesFraction(68.5)
GO
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If fraction is not concern (1/2) then you can try with below script

```
DECLARE @1 DECIMAL(5,2)
SELECT @1 = 68.5

SELECT  CAST(FLOOR(@1/12) AS VARCHAR)+''' ' + CAST(Floor(@1%12)  AS VARCHAR) +  '.' + CAST(CAST((ABS(@1%12)-Floor(@1%12)) * 10 AS INT) AS VARCHAR) +'"'
```